# Problems with mod rewrite and the use of a period as a delimiter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to rewrite this:

```
somewebsite.com/john.doe
```

To:

```
somewebsite.com/customerlookup.php?fname=john&lname=doe
```

I cannot get it to work with a period as a delimiter, I can get it working with a `,` or a `-` or `/` but not with a period using this code.

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)$ /customerlookup.php?fname=$1&lname=$2 [L]
```

Here is my .htaccess file,

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$ /index.php?fname=$1&lname=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$ index.php?fname=$1&lname=$2 [L]
```

Since dot is used on regex that would escape it.

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: @BrandonRoloff do you have any other rules, please update your question with your full `.htaccess`

Comment: Options -Multiviews  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$ /index.php?fname=$1&lname=$2 [L]

Comment: Try the update I have posted, I tried it myself and its fully working, if you get an internal server error with an exact copy then you should check your PHP file and error log.

Comment: Okay that worked but now my css files are broken.  When you goto http://somewebsite.com/css/somefile.css it just redirects to the homepage.  Any ideas?

Comment: @BrandonRoloff Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` above the lowest RewriteRule. It will redirect only if file does not exist. Or capture in RewriteRule should check for slashes.

Comment: @BrandonRoloff like Cheery suggested its better if you verify if files/folders exist before doing the redirect to avoid redirecting those, I've updated the rule to reflect that.